# Как объявить параметр output хранимой процедуры в C#?

Tags: c#, sql

```
EXEC    @return_value = [Obj_Insert2]
        @Check = 1,
        @cID = @cID OUTPUT

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

как объявить обычный параметр @check понятно

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Check", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
```

Comment: Создайте SqlParameter в отдельной переменной. У него есть свойство Direction, там enum, выберите Output. После этого добавляйте параметр в команду

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать отдельно объект `SqlParameter` и установить его свойства:

```
        SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter("@cID", SqlDbType.Int);
        par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        par.Value = value;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(par);
```

Или же сразу добавить параметр в команду:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cID", value).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```